# FTP Client that can share common site entries across multiple users?

Tags: ftp

I am trying to find an FTP client that can share a config/site entries file with multiple users.

Currently everyone at my office is using WS_FTP, and with some hackery (as instructed by WS_FTP tech support) we have it working off of a central file. So if anyone adds a new site, makes edits to existing sites, etc... we all see it when we open our local version of WS_FTP.

Great...except WS_FTP is proving to be very buggy (slow to load, freezes, crashes, acts just plain weird and jumps around folders).

Seems to me this would be a pretty common thing for web companies to want to do, but I can't find anything to suggest other FTP programs can do this ("out of the box", or with hacks).

Any suggestions for a FTP client that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

FileZilla can do what you are describing. And it is a free open source application. I did like the progress information in WS_FTP better myself, but switched to FileZilla a while ago and other than that, fills all my needs as well or better then WS_FTP.

To sync your users to a common list, just sync the sitemanager.xml file with all your users. For Windows based clients, this file is located in %APPDATA%\FileZilla.  For non-Windows clients, this would be the ~/.filezilla folder instead. Refer to:

http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FAQ

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything about it on the FileZilla site before, but I'll try what you've suggested and look at that link. Thanks.